# Styles with PHP

Tags: css

I am trying to set the width of some data from a database, so that all data is the same lenght.

I am using (for a test), the following CSS:

```
style='width: 200px; border: 1px solid black;'
```

This is within a bold tag, again just for testing.

The result is not what I want. [image]

The bottom text uses the following css:

`.pwidth {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}`

I want the data after PID: to look like the demo ex show.

What am I missing?

```
<body>

<section>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="text-center">Index Of Records</h1>
        <h2 class="text-center">Add New Record <a href='insert_record.php'>(x)</a><h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container">

        <?php
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<div><strong>PID:</strong>";
                echo "<b style='width: 200px; border: 1px solid black;'>". $row["pid"]. "</span></b>";
                }
            } else {
                    echo "No records to view.";
                    }
            $con->close();
        ?>          
        <p class="pwidth">demo ex show<p>
    </div><!-- container end -->    
</section>
```

Comment: Again. What PHP got in common with styles?

Comment: Can you show your html code?

Comment: You really have to learn something about block and inline elements. try this link: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

Answer (score 1):

**Try This One**

```
<section>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="text-center">Index Of Records</h1>

        <h2 class="text-center">Add New Record <a href='insert_record.php'>(x)</a>

            <h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container">

        <?php
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<div><strong>PID:</strong>";
                echo "<p style='width: 200px; border: 1px solid black;'>" . $row["pid"] . "</span></p>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "No records to view.";
        }
        $con->close();
        ?>

        <p class="pwidth">demo ex show</p>
    </div>
    <!-- container end -->
</section>
```

Comment: What does this do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out markup. Explain yourself!

Answer (score 0):

What kind of an element is your "pwidth"? You may use an HTML-Block-Element to set a width.

So maybe `<p>, <div>` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

a `<b>` tag is not block or inline-block element so it can't have width/padding/margin values.

You can add trigger those bold tags with Class in CSS and make them `display: block;`